# C programming segmentation fault error and wrong outputs when using linked list

Tags: c, linux, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been experimenting using simple linked lists in C however I am getting the wrong outputs followed by a segmentation fault error.

The purpose of this program is two get 3 parameters from a text file and place them within a linked list as an object. Each time a new line is read it will be placed within the list using the method `newData` and will eventually be displayed to the console using the `display` method.

However when I try to do this I only output the final item added to the linked list and
it is displayed the amount of lines present within my text file which is followed by a segmentation fault error and I cannot fathom why.

If anyone knows the issue or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. The code is shown below.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "param.h"
#include "function.h"
#include "lists.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *p1;
int p2;
int p3;
FILE *in;
char *temp;
char param[100];


in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
while (fgets(param,100,in) != NULL) {
    temp = strdup(param);
    p1 = strsep(&temp,",");
    p2 = atoi(strsep(&temp,","));
    p3 = atoi(strsep(&temp,","));

    newData(p1,p2,p3);
    free(temp);
}

fclose(in);
display();
return 0;
}
```

lists.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "param.h"
#include "function.h"
#include "lists.h"

static struct node*head;
static struct parameters tempTaskObject;
static int status = 1;

void newData(char * p1, int p2, int p3){
if (status == 1)
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

tempTaskObject.p1 = p1;
tempTaskObject.p2 = p2;
tempTaskObject.p3 = p3; 

insert(&head,&tempTaskObject);
status = 0;
}

void display(){
traverse(head);
}
```

function.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "function.h"
#include "param.h"

void insert(struct node **head, Parameters *newParameters) {
struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

newNode->parameters = newParameters;
newNode->next = *head;
*head = newNode;

}


void traverse(struct node *head) {
struct node *temp;
temp = head;

while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("[%s] [%d] [%d]\n",temp->parameters->p1, temp->parameters->p2, temp->parameters->p3);
    temp = temp->next;
}
}
```

param.h:

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

typedef struct parameters {
char *p1;
int p2;
int p3;
} Parameters;

#endif
```

lists.h:

```
#define MIN_PRIORITY 1
#define MAX_PRIORITY 10

void newData(char *p1, int p2, int p3);
void display();
```

function.h:

```
#include "param.h"

struct node {
Parameters * parameters;
struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node **head, Parameters * parameters);
void traverse(struct node *head);
```

[Test Input 1]:

```
P1, 1, 11
P2, 2, 22
P3, 3, 33
P4, 4, 44
P5, 5, 55
P6, 6, 66
P7, 7, 77
P8, 8, 88
```

[Test Output 1]:

```
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
P8, 8, 88
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

[Test Input 2]:

```
P1, 1, 11
P2, 2, 22
P3, 3, 33
```

[Test Output 2]:

```
P3, 3, 33
P3, 3, 33
P3, 3, 33
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Yes I did my bad

Comment: your `traverse` function run until it sees `NULL`, but `head` is not NULL and is not initialized to have `NULL` in `next`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output as text instead of showing images. I suggest to use a memory access checker like `valgrind` or run your program in a debugger, execute it step-by-step

Comment: Vlad has raised some good points in the answer below. Your seg fault comes from the uninitialized and unmotivated dummy head node that you create on the first insertion. Dummy nodes are a pattern that one sees often with beginner's code on SO. The practice seems to stem from a false belief that the head pointer should not be null, but a null head just means your list is empty. In fact, your `insert` function handles prepending a node to an amty list already. Get rid of the `status` stuff.

Comment: So from what I understand my linked list will get a segmentation fault error since my head with no data is not equal to NULL. Would a fix for this be making "head = NULL;" after my insert() method runs? Also im not sure I entirely understand why my list has the same value for all its entries. From what I am getting it is because I am always referring to the same object which replaces the value for each part of the list. If I am right about this part does anyone know a way to solve this issue?

Comment: No, saying `head = NULL` after inserting will empty the list and will lose the inserted node. Just don't create an uninitialized dummy node. You don't need it and it gives you the segfault when you want to access its `parameters`. Just remove the `status` variable and the `if (status == 1) ...` block.

Comment: It's like this: Your `head` is `NULL` at the beginning. (It's a `static` variable at file scope, which will be initialized to null or zero.) When you insert a new node, you create a node with `malloc`, copy the data and then set `next` to the old head. If that's the first node, you set `next` to `NULL`, which is what it should look like on the last node. All's good.

Comment: But why does your printout print the same parameters? Because your nodes hold pointers to parameters and there's only one object of type `Parameters` in the whole code: `tempTaskObject`. You use it as scratch space in `newData`, but since all nodes hold pointers to the same object, it will print its last state. It might be better to make the `parameters` member of your node a plain struct `Parameters`, not a `Parameters *`.

Comment: I see the problem is when I remove the status code I get the same output results expect I only get one output line before getting a segmentation error. I initially tried the status variable after noticing I would get output lines equal to my input lines when without I would only get one.

Comment: I've explained that: Your `node->parameters` all point to the same data. [Here](https://ideone.com/biFdoh)'s a version of your code that stores a struct, not a pointer to a struct in the nodes. You should get different data in different nodes.

Comment: Oh I see I was pointing to an address. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters in this while loop

```
while (fgets(param,100,in) != NULL) {
    temp = strdup(param);
    p1 = strsep(&temp,",");
    p2 = atoi(strsep(&temp,","));
    p3 = atoi(strsep(&temp,","));

    newData(p1,p2,p3);
    free(temp);
}
```

the call of free

```
free(temp);
```

does not make an effect because temp will be equal to NULL.

On the other hand, the function `newData` also can invoke undefined behavior because it uses uninitialized object of the type `struct node` when it is called the first time passing it to the function insert.

```
if (status == 1)
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

Also you are always using a pointer to the same global object `static struct parameters tempTaskObject;` in this initializing statement

```
newNode->parameters = newParameters;
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to define functions such a way when they depend on numerous global variables.

Comment: Interestingly, the `free(temp)` doesn't do any harm here, because `strsep` modifies `temp` and with the given input, it is `NULL` after three calls. (But that whole code block suffers from missing error checking.)

Comment: @MOehm  Oh, you are write provided that temp will be equal to NULL after the third call of the function strsep.

Comment: Yes, that's very brittle code: If the line has fewer than three fields, you get UB with `atoi`. If it has more than three fields, you get UB on an illegal `free`.